# setTimeinterval stops when right-clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, timer

I'm building a quiz of some sort with a built in timer.
It's all working great and the timer sets the score depending on how fast you answer the question.
Only problem is - when someone right click the document the timer stops, and that user can think about the question, maybe google it from a mobile device or what not.
I've tried blocking right click using JS, but since its a facebook app if someone right clicks outside of the app frame - the timer still stops.

Any ideas on how to create a timer that can run regardless right clicks?
Thanks ahead!

Comment: In what browser did you experience this? I've never heard of rightclicks suppressing intervals. Also, please post your code that is needed to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Bergi: Good point, right-clicking doesn't seem to stop a `setInterval` timer in Firefox, Chrome, or Opera: http://jsbin.com/afotoRA/1 It **does** in IE10. (sigh) I still don't think I'd use that kind of timer for *timing* things, but perhaps for the "time's up!" message or similar.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Interesting. How exactly does this work? Does the callback not fire while the button is down (while the context menu is open?), or are all scheduled timeouts canceled from a right click? Of course it's known that timeouts are unreliable :-)

Comment: @Bergi: The callbacks don't get called while the right-click menu is showing, then (in the case of `setInterval`) they start getting called again when you remove the menu. I didn't check what happens with `setTimeout`, but my guess is that the callback waits and then is executed when the menu disappears.

Comment: @Bergi: I just had to check, and it's weird, it's like the timers are suspended while the menu is open: http://jsbin.com/afotoRA/2 If I run that, right-click fairly early on, and then wait several seconds before dismissing the menu, the callback of the `setTimeout(..., 2000)` that I scheduled **doesn't** fire instantly when the menu disappears. V. strange. V. IE.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use `setInterval` or `setTimeout` for this. Instead, I'd record when they started viewing the question, and when they answered it, and take the difference.

Of course, if this information is held client-side, all bets are off. :-) Even if you send the information to the server, you'd have to have some mechanism for dealing with the inevitable hand-crafted HTTP requests from people trying to cheat.

Answer (score 0):

U can make an event for mouse right click :

`$('#element').mousedown(function(event) {
    if (event.which ==3) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});`

or like this:

```
$(document).bind("contextmenu",function(e){
    return false;
    $('.alert').fadeToggle(); // this line never gets called
});
```